# Start reading an Excel sheet at a specified row

Tags: java, excel, sax, xssf

I am reading an Excel file using POI's XSSF and SAX (Event API). The Excel sheet has thousands of rows so this is the only way that I have found to have good performance. Now I would like to read Excel file from one particularly row, for example row 6 because these Excel files are updated every day and I store the last row that I have already stored so I can read only the new rows.

How can I start from one row?

```
private void getExcelField(AcquisitionForm acquisitionForm) throws ExcelReadException, IOException{
    InputStream stream=null;
    OPCPackage p=null;
    try{
        p = OPCPackage.open(acquisitionForm.getDatatablePath(), PackageAccess.READ);
        ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(p);
        XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(p);
        StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
        XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();
        int index = 0;
        //Test with one sheet
        iter.hasNext();
        //(iter.hasNext()) {
        stream = iter.next();
        String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();
        processSheet(styles, strings, stream, acquisitionForm);
        stream.close();
        //++index;
        //}
        p.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new ExcelReadException("An error occured during excel file reading ", e);
    }finally{ 
        if (stream!=null)
            stream.close();
        if (p!=null)
            p.close();
        //++index;
        // }
    }

}



/**
 * Parses and shows the content of one sheet
 * using the specified styles and shared-strings tables.
 * @param styles
 * @param strings
 * @param sheetInputStream
 * @throws ExcelReadException 
 */
private void processSheet(StylesTable styles, ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, InputStream sheetInputStream, AcquisitionForm acquisitionForm) throws Exception {
    InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
    SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    //ContentHandler handler = new MyXSSFSheetHandler(styles, strings);
    MyXSSFSheetHandler handler = new MyXSSFSheetHandler(styles, strings,databaseAcquisitionServices, acquisitionForm);
    sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
    sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
}
```

MyXSSFSheetHandler

```
public MyXSSFSheetHandler(StylesTable styles, ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings,DatabaseAcquisitionServices databaseAcquisitionServices, AcquisitionForm acquisitionForm, int sheetIndex) {
    this.stylesTable = styles;
    this.sharedStringsTable = strings;
    this.formatter = new DataFormatter();
    this.value = new StringBuffer();
    this.nextDataType = XssfDataType.NUMBER;
    this.databaseAcquisitionServices=databaseAcquisitionServices;
    this.acquisitionForm=acquisitionForm;
    this.sheetIndex = sheetIndex;
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if ("inlineStr".equals(name) || "v".equals(name)) {
        vIsOpen = true;
        // Clear contents cache
        value.setLength(0);
    }
    // c => cell
    else if ("c".equals(name)) {
        // Get the cell reference
        cellCoordinate = attributes.getValue("r");
        int firstDigit = -1;
        for (int c = 0; c < cellCoordinate.length(); ++c) {
            if (Character.isDigit(cellCoordinate.charAt(c))) {
                firstDigit = c;
                break;
            }
        }
        thisColumn = nameToColumn(cellCoordinate.substring(0, firstDigit));

        // Set up defaults.
        this.nextDataType = XssfDataType.NUMBER;
        this.formatIndex = -1;
        this.formatString = null;
        String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
        String cellStyleStr = attributes.getValue("s");
        if ("b".equals(cellType)) {
            nextDataType = XssfDataType.BOOL;
        } else if ("e".equals(cellType)) {
            nextDataType = XssfDataType.ERROR;
        } else if ("inlineStr".equals(cellType)) {
            nextDataType = XssfDataType.INLINESTR;
        } else if ("s".equals(cellType)) {
            nextDataType = XssfDataType.SSTINDEX;
        } else if ("str".equals(cellType)) {
            nextDataType = XssfDataType.FORMULA;
        } else if (cellStyleStr != null) {
            // It's a number, but almost certainly one
            //  with a special style or format 
            int styleIndex = Integer.parseInt(cellStyleStr);
            XSSFCellStyle style = stylesTable.getStyleAt(styleIndex);
            this.formatIndex = style.getDataFormat();
            this.formatString = style.getDataFormatString();
            if (this.formatString == null) {
                this.formatString = BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(this.formatIndex);
            }
        }
    }

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#endElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 */
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
        throws SAXException {



    String cellValue = null;
    //String thisStr = null;

    // v => contents of a cell
    if ("v".equals(name)) {
        // Process the value contents as required.
        // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
        switch (nextDataType) {

        case BOOL:
            char first = value.charAt(0);
            //thisStr = first == '0' ? "FALSE" : "TRUE";
            //cellValue= new Boolean(first =='0' ? false: true);
            cellValue=first == '0' ? "false" : "true";
            break;

        case ERROR:
            //thisStr = "\"ERROR:" + value.toString() + '"';
            cellValue=new String(value.toString());
            break;

        case FORMULA:
            // A formula could result in a string value,
            // so always add double-quote characters.
            //thisStr = '"' + value.toString() + '"';
            cellValue=new String(value.toString());
            break;

        case INLINESTR:
            XSSFRichTextString rtsi = new XSSFRichTextString(value.toString());
            //thisStr = '"' + rtsi.toString() + '"';
            cellValue=new String(rtsi.toString());
            break;

        case SSTINDEX:
            String sstIndex = value.toString();
            try {
                int idx = Integer.parseInt(sstIndex);
                XSSFRichTextString rtss = new XSSFRichTextString(sharedStringsTable.getEntryAt(idx));
                //  thisStr = '"' + rtss.toString() + '"';
                cellValue=new String(rtss.toString());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse SST index '" + sstIndex + "': " + ex.toString());
            }
            break;

        case NUMBER:
            String n = value.toString();
            if (this.formatString != null && n.length() > 0){
                cellValue = formatter.formatRawCellContents(Double.parseDouble(n), this.formatIndex, this.formatString);
                //cellValue=new Double(Double.parseDouble(n));
            }
            else{
                //thisStr = n;
                cellValue=new String(n);
            }
            break;

        default:
            cellValue="";
            //thisStr = "(TODO: Unexpected type: " + nextDataType + ")";
            break;
        }

        // Output after we've seen the string contents
        // Emit commas for any fields that were missing on this row
        if (lastColumnNumber == -1) {
            lastColumnNumber = 0;
        }
        //          for (int i = lastColumnNumber; i < thisColumn; ++i){
        //              System.out.print(',');
        //          }


        // Might be the empty string.
        rowValues.put(cellCoordinate,cellValue);
        //System.out.print(cellValue);

        // Update column
        if (thisColumn > -1)
            lastColumnNumber = thisColumn;

    } else if ("row".equals(name)) {
        // We're onto a new row

        //I have to pass new HashMap because otherwise all the map into archiveAcquisition have the same values
        databaseAcquisitionServices.archiveAcquisition(new TreeMap<>(rowValues), rowCounter, acquisitionForm, sheetIndex);
        //Clear the structure used to store row data
        rowValues.clear();
        rowCounter++;
        //System.out.println();
        lastColumnNumber = -1;
    }

}

/**
 * Captures characters only if a suitable element is open.
 * Originally was just "v"; extended for inlineStr also.
 */
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (vIsOpen)
        value.append(ch, start, length);
}

/**
 * Converts an Excel column name like "C" to a zero-based index.
 *
 * @param name
 * @return Index corresponding to the specified name
 */
private int nameToColumn(String name) {
    int column = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {
        int c = name.charAt(i);
        column = (column + 1) * 26 + c - 'A';
    }
    return column;
}
```

Comment: nothing? Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to count the number of rows that you see in a class derived from `SheetContentsHandler`, I don't think you need to have a separate `XSSFSheetHAndler`, I would rather use the default one and only have a dervied `SheetContentsHandler` which has callback-methods for all the things that you are interested in, e.g. `startRow`, `endRow`, `cell`.

You can take a look at the [XLSX2CSV sample](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) for an example of how streaming reading of XLSX files can be done, especially how the class `SheetToCSV` is used to get calls for each row/cell, you could e.g. use something like `if (currentRow < startRow) { return }` in the method `cell()` to skip rows.

The cell-method is called with a parameter `String cellReference` which can be used to retrieve the row/cell coordinates via `new CellReference(cellReference).getCol()` and `new CellReference(cellReference).getRow()`.

Comment: I added my actual code, the start row I have to retrieve from database. I have to add condition on start row in startElement?

Comment: As said in my answer, I would not try to re-implement the XSSFSheetHandler, I would rather use a custom SheetContentsHandler as shown in the XLSX2CSV sample that I linked to, this way you need to do much less work yourself as all the Row/Cell-parsing is taken care of by POI already.

Comment: Sorry but This is my first time with excel in java. If I understand I have to create SheetToCSV implements SheetContentsHandler and in cell methods add if. But If I use this code, my class MyXSSFSheetHandler doesn't need?
I don't have to show but I have to store cell coordinate and value into TreeMap

Comment: Yep, you would build something similar than SheetToCSV where you do the processing, MyXSSFSheetHandler can then be removed.

Comment: But how can I retrieve the cell coordinates from that code and how can I recognize the new rows?

Comment: I updated the answer with a paragraph about coordinates, for "new rows" I don't know what you mean as I don't know (and likely don't even want to know :) ) what you would like to do exactly.

Comment: I'm trying to write code like your sample, I'll let you know. For new row I mean a new row of Excel file because I must call one method for each row and I need also index. The currentRow variable in bad (is also -1)